# How to make html date input always show the date picker

Tags: html, css, html-input

[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kNBy.png)
Is there a way to make the date picker always active and not disappear?

I want to only show the date picker and so far I've figured out that I can use the opacity to hide the displayed date.

If it's possible to do with only html+css it would be great.

ps: I don't know what are the input fields called so to be on the same page:
[Img](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N9LuI.png)

Comment: Keep in mind that to use that method, transient user activation is required. The user has to interact with the page or a UI element in order for this feature to work.